# Exception never seems to get thrown when an AxisFault is found

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have this `catch` statement:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof AxisFault) {
        LOGGER.info("AxisFault: " + e);
        if (((AxisFault) e).getFaultReason().contains("My error text")) {
            throw new MyServiceException(HPDatastoreProviderImpl.class.toString(),
                    "My error text");
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Failed: " + e);
    }
}
```

When it's hit I can see that `LOGGER.info("AxisFault: " + e);` seems to be ignored. The `if` statement is entered and I can see the debugger on line `throw new MyServiceException(HiPlusDatastoreProviderImpl.class.toString(), "My error text");` but then it jumps to `LOGGER.info("Failed: " + e);`.

If I remove `LOGGER.info("AxisFault: " + e);` the `if` is never entered. It jumps straight to the `else`. `MyServiceException` never actually seems to be thrown. How do I resolve this?

**Update**

I updated my catch to:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e.getMessage().contains("My error text")) {
        throw new MyServiceException(HPDatastoreProviderImpl.class.toString(),
                "My error text");
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Failed: " + e);
    }
}
```

The `if` doesn't get entered but on the `catch` I can see `e={AxisFault@1914} "My error text` in my debugger. That's the reason I thought this was an access fault. I feel I'm no further on with this.

Comment: if it goes to that failed, it isn't an instance of AxisFault, and is quite normal that it won't execute that code

Comment: Why would it even enter `if (e instanceof AxisFault) {`?

Comment: as it goes into the else block, it obviously doesn't. It checks that condition, finds that it's false, and goes to the else block

Comment: Makes sense. I added an update to my query.

Comment: it might be another class compared to the one you compare with, just having the same name

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: myJava.myClass.Test = new myJava.myClass.Test("test"); Test second = new Test("test"); on first view, these might be the same. But if second is an instance of myJava.myImplementation.Test, second instanceof myJava.myClass.Test will return false

Comment: I get that. I'm trying to compare two strings though - the exception string with my message string. Am I missing something?

Comment: have you debugged it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to have been some issue with my environment. After clearing my browser cache, restarting my laptop, then rebuilding the application it finally worked. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.